# How to create a slide down menu bar on scroll in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to create a slide down navbar in my angular2 such that if it's scrolled down, the menu disappears, then on scroll up the menu bar reappears.

```
<div class="nav-bar>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to go about this in angular2 typescript component.

Answer (score 0):

Create mavigation item model

```
export class Navigation {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 displayed: boolean;
 url: string;
}
```

After that you have two options, serve it from DB, or create new itemn based on model.

Second option in main class:

```
nav[]: Navigation[] = [];

constructor(public navigation: Navigation) {
let navigationHome = new Navigation(); 
navigationHome = {
 id:1,
 title: "home",
 displayed: true,
 url: "/home"
}
  [...]


this.nav.push(navigationHome, [...])
}
```

And display it in HTML, inside router html. I have done it like this, but I serve it from db across subscribe.

Comment: This is an example of what am taking about in javascript [ https://codepen.io/sunnyxyst/pen/DwgFm ]